# Laravel authentication not working npm install&&npm run dev

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8

I did composer create-project laravel/laravel Push "8.0"

In blog file do.

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap

php artisan ui vue --auth

Then change package.json file to :
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json#L12

Then do npm install --save-dev cross-env

npm install vue

Second do npm install&&npm run dev

chenasmartin@MacBook-Air-von-Chenas Push % npm install&&npm run dev

up to date, audited 788 packages in 736ms

81 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> dev
> npm run development

> development
> mix

✖ Mix
Compiled with some errors in 785.65ms

WARNING in ./resources/js/bootstrap.js 4:2-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/resources/js'
Did you mean './bootstrap'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
8 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
resources/sass/app.scss 8:9  root stylesheet
at processResult (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:19)
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:853:5
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
at context.callback (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7
at Function.call$2 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:98905:16)
at render_closure1.call$2 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:84431:12)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:29484:18)
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28006:21)
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28313:49)
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3896:77)
at _Future._completeError$2 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28159:9)
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:27807:12)
at Object._asyncRethrow (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:3699:17)
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Push/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:19760:20

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning

How can i fix that

Answer (score 0):

**Try to install bootstrap manually** with npm so you run the following command:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

If this not work, you can manually switch back to node-sass,

Run the following command to install the node-sass dependencies:

```
npm install node-sass
```

Now change the following code :

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css', {
     implementation: require('node-sass')
});
```

Comment: were do i have to put the following code mix.sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css etc

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` folder and retry to run :

```
npm install
```